# URLの配列を作りたい

Tags: ios, objective-c

URLの配列を作りたいのですが、なかなかうまくできません。。。

```
NSURL *url1 = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.ajisaba.net/motion/dnld.php?fpath=emu.mp4"]; 
NSURL *url2 = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.ajisaba.net/motion/dnld.php?fpath=penguin.mp4"];      
NSArray *urls = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:url1,url2,nil]; 
MPMoviePlayerController *moviePlayerController = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc]initWithContentURL:urls];
```

とするとエラーがでてしまいます。。 
どなたか教えてください、よろしくお願い致します。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

まず、タイトルと問題点が一致していないように見受けられます。

```
NSURL *url1 = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.ajisaba.net/motion/dnld.php?fpath=emu.mp4"]; 
NSURL *url2 = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.ajisaba.net/motion/dnld.php?fpath=penguin.mp4"];      
NSArray *urls = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:url1,url2,nil];
```

ここまででURLの配列は作成できていると思います。

本文から印象を受けた問題点としては、おそらくMPMoviePlayerControllerにプレイリストを設定したいということなのかと思いますが、M.I.Aさんが記載しているようにMPMoviePlayerControllerは引数に配列を取るクラスではないため、そのまま配列は渡せません。

MPMoviePlayerControllerには様々なNotificationが用意されているので、  
それらをうまく利用して順次再生できるつくりにするのが良いと思います。
※Notificationについては下記公式Referenceをご参照ください。

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MediaPlayer/Reference/MPMoviePlayerController_Class/index.html

Comment: なるほどです...ありがとうございました！

Answer (score 1):

```
MPMoviePlayerController *moviePlayerController = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc]initWithContentURL:urls];
```

上記のメソッド"initWithContentURL:"の引数の型はNSURLクラスです。あなたはNSArrayクラスのオブジェクトurlsを指定しているため、エラーになっていると考えられます。
url1かurl2を指定すればエラーはなくなると思います。

Comment: ありがとうございます！助かりました。